# Stop browser requesting to save password

Tags: forms, passwords, browser

Is this possible to force browser not to prompt to save the password? I don't want to let my user to save their password in the browser. Any idea from the experts?

Comment: Please don't do this. Let the user choose to save their details if they want to.

Comment: But i need to. I am developing an application that need to have close access functionality that can be accessed by only few people. If i let it then some user might save their credential and that is a big security leak. I really need a solution to this. And thanks for your comment @Grim...

Comment: If that's the case, then you might want to find a different authentication method - any method you use (including mine below) can be gotten around very easily (I have a plugin that removes autocomplete values, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off `autocomplete`.

`<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: This won't work with IE11 and soon Firefox (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229507/how-to-disable-autocomplete-for-a-html-password-field-in-ie11)

Comment: Good. It's a horrible thing to do to a user, in my opinion. See also: not letting me paste things into form objects.