# Disable autocomplete off on old browsers

Tags: html, forms

Can anybody help me in knowing that how to disable autocomplete feature of web browser in old browsers like firefox ver less than 3.5....

I tried `autocomplete=off` attribute on both form tag and input tag but no luck

Comment: You will soon find that `autocomplete=off` will also no longer work in modern browsers... It is already dropped in IE11, Firefox will be dropping it soon. This link has a couple of ideas how to get around this for IE11 and they may also work for the older browsers which you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229507/how-to-disable-autocomplete-for-a-html-password-field-in-ie11/20809203#20809203

Comment: Any more ideas to accomplish same?

Comment: Anything you do will need to be a "hack". Browsers are giving back control to the end user and taking this type of option away from the developers. If an end user decides to use auto complete, that is their choice and we should not be able to override that. I understand, I am in the same situation. Say we add in a feature to change password with a "current password" field... thanks to auto complete, that has been pre-populated... Its pointless!